# Makefile - how to add command flags conditionally

Tags: makefile

Example using makefile with ansible(but question is for any command):

```
deploy:
      ansible-playbook ansible/playbook-deploy.yml \
        -i ansible/environments/$(ENV)/inventory \
      -e "$(ARGS)" \
      --tags="$(TAGS)" \
      --skip-tags="$(SKIP_TAGS)" \
      $2 2>&1 | tee -a ${LOG_PATH}
```

Now I want to skip adding -e , --tags, --skip-tags flags if the variables are correspondingly empty ARGS/TAGS/SKIP_TAGS

Something like this will not work
`ifdef ARGS -e "$(ARGS)" \ endif`

I am begginer to makefiles so errors are expected, so please advise me for resources how to implement this case, thanks

I don't want to add `\` then in next line `--tags=...` if TAGS variable is not defined, same for the others

Answer (score 2):

A simple way is to use make's `$(if ...)` function, like this:

```
ansible-args = $(if $(ARGS),-e '$(ARGS)') \
               $(if $(TAGS),--tags='$(TAGS)') \
               $(if $(SKIP_TAGS),--skip-tags='$(SKIP_TAGS)')

deploy:
        ansible-playbook ansible/playbook-deploy.yml \
               -i ansible/environments/$(ENV)/inventory \
               $(ansible-args) $2 2>&1 | tee -a ${LOG_PATH}
```

Comment: will this add also `\` conditioanlly, from what i understand from snippet that is added even if args, tags is not defined ?

Comment: I have no idea what the `$2` here is intended to represent: that will always be empty unless somewhere in your makefile you are setting the make variable named `2` to some value...?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand the question.  Your best bet is to try it and see and if it doesn't do what you want, then update your question with more specifics of the problem.

Comment: Good catch! removed $2, forgot to delete it. It has some value before migration to makefile when i used it in bash. No you understood totally correct the question, i mean only that conditionally also `\` and newline should be added in best case, not just the --tags=... and so on

Comment: I don't understand about the `''`.  They will appear (again, it's simpler to just try it than have an extended discussion here about it).  Make doesn't care anything about quotes of any kind.  They're just another character to make and will be included as if they were an `a` or a `b`.  As for the newline, you can either have no newlines when the values are set, or you can have empty lines with backslashes when the variables are not set, but you can't have both.

Answer (score -1):

This will work, found first solution but is very ugly and I don't like it.
Want to learn most elegant solution so looking for answers.

```
ifdef ARGS
    $(eval args=-e='$(ARGS)')
endif
ifdef TAGS
    $(eval tags=--tags='$(TAGS)')
endif
ifdef SKIP_TAGS
    $(eval skipTags=--skip-tags='$(SKIP_TAGS)')
endif

    ansible-playbook ansible/playbook-deploy.yml \
        -i ansible/environments/$(ENV)/inventory \
      $(args) \
      $(tags) \
      $(skipTags) \
      $2 2>&1 | tee -a ${LOG_PATH}
```

Also here command will be super ugly if no args tags skiptags specified like

```
ansible-playbook ansible/playbook-deploy.yml \
        -i ansible/environments/development/inventory \
       \
   \
       \
       2>&1 | tee -a logs/development/2021-07-04_17_46_45.log
```

Comment: You don't need the `eval` here.  In fact `eval` is a very advanced feature: almost no "normal" makefile will need it.

Comment: @MadScientist thanks, please suggest me alternative then what to use instead. currently eval is getting job done but i am happy with suggestion to replace it

Comment: If you are happy with `eval` then why ask on SO?

Comment: Because i notice is not clean code and want to learn proper way of doing. I though you refered tousage of eval for declaring the vars misudnerstood you, but you referred to the if conditions. Will try the if snippet below thanks trying to remove also `\` conditionally

Comment: I'm talking about eval.  Eval should not be used inside a recipe.  Doing so will work (I didn't say it wouldn't) but it's a bad idea.  Either assign the variables outside the recipe using normal make assignment, or use shell variables inside the recipe.  But if you want something cleaner, I recommend not using _either_ `ifdef` _or_ `eval` and instead doing something like what I have in my answer.